# In SQL. Why does this 'Like' statement with a wildcard not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Declare @Temp1 as nvarchar(max) = '[10004120][1100][10033583][1005]'
Declare @Temp2 as nvarchar(max) = '[10004120][1100]'

If @Temp1 like @Temp2 + '%'
    Print 'Yup'
```

Why does this not work? I don't get the "yup" message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't work because the brackets in the string have a special function in a LIKE statement - items between the brackets constitute a set of values that the singular character at the specified position matches. Your original pattern looks for a 1,0,4, or 2 followed by a 1 or an 0. To make this work, you should have a pattern like this:

```
Declare @Temp2 as nvarchar(max) = '[[]10004120][[]1100]'
```

Comment: Okay. That makes sense. Unfortunately I cannot change the string values since they are the sorting order that gets attached to each row.

Assuming i have item A which has a sort order like '[10004120][1100]'. How can I get all items where the sort order is past that item. Like '[10004120][1100][10033583][1005]'.

Comment: Use REPLACE, e.g. `If @Temp1 like REPLACE(@Temp2, '[', '[[]') + '%' Print 'Yup'`

Comment: Sorry to bug you with this. Your solution does work so I will mark it as an answer. 

But does your solution have any benefit over something like

`If Substring(@Temp1,0,LEN(@Temp2)+1) = @Temp2
 Print 'Yup'`

Comment: Only that a LIKE on the first part of a field will use an index, whereas the SUBSTRING solution does not appear to do so. If the field isn't indexed, one is as good as another.

Answer (score 2):

You have the `like` backwards.  The pattern is the *second* operand.  The logic should be:

```
 @temp1 like @temp2 + '%'
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.I will edit the code to reflect this change though

Comment: Could it be operator precedence?  Maybe need parenths `(@temp2 + '%')`  (Shouldn't be a problem, `+` should be evaluated first https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/operator-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @AaronLS. I tried adding in parenthesis. I also tried both sides of the like statement with the parenthesis. None worked so far

Answer (score 2):

At least in MS Sql Server, the square brackets have meaning in a LIKE.
They are a bit similar to a character class in regex.

For example:

`WHERE col LIKE '[0-9]%'` will find col values that start with a digit.
`WHERE col LIKE '%[^0-9]'` will find col values that end with anything but a digit.

So something as a `LIKE '[10004120][1100]%'` is equivalent to a `LIKE '[0-24][01]%'` and will actually match with strings like '11X', '40Y'.

But in this case you don't have to use LIKE.
Since the first string just has to start with the second string.

```
IF @Temp2 = LEFT(@Temp1, LEN(@Temp2))
PRINT 'yup'
```

And to check if the second string is a part of the first string.
You could use CHARINDEX. Which will return 1 if it's found at the start.

```
IF CHARINDEX(@Temp2, @Temp1) > 0
BEGIN 
   PRINT 'yup'
END
```

Comment: Thank you. Another user pointed this out as well. 

Is there another way to check? I need to find all items that are further down the chain from a specific item. 

In the above example. The temp1 item has a sort location of '[10004120][1100][10033583][1005]'. And the temp2 has a sort order of '[10004120][1100]'. 

So i want to find all items where the sort order is equal to temp2 sort order + '%'.

Comment: `If @Temp1 = LEFT(@Temp2, LEN(@Temp1))` -- Stop. Flip that -- Continue: `If @Temp2 = LEFT(@Temp1, LEN(@Temp2))`

Comment: @LaughingVergil Thx. You are correct. Had it backwards. Doh.

Comment: Thanks! This solution works as well. 

So between using SUBSTRING, using REPLACE, and using LEFT. Which one is better? I think the SUBSTRING or LEFT are easier to read or understand whereas the REPLACE might require some explanation.

Comment: @StephanusDJ  Yup. It's basically because `%` `_` and the square brackets only mean something in a LIKE or a PATINDEX.

Comment: And to choose between SUBSTRING or LEFT? I see LEFT and RIGHT as limited versions of SUBSTRING. There should be no difference in performance between them. So whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than add a specific pattern for an open bracket, I would use [the optional ESCAPE clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for LIKE expressions:

```
Declare @Temp1 as nvarchar(max) = '[10004120][1100][10033583][1005]'
Declare @Temp2 as nvarchar(max) = '[10004120][1100]'

If @Temp1 LIKE REPLACE(@Temp2, '[', '\[') + '%' ESCAPE '\'
    Print 'Yup'
```

To me that's cleaner and more explicit about what you're trying to accomplish.  Obviously, you've got to pick an escape character that's guaranteed not to be in your data or otherwise use `@Temp1 LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(@Temp2, '\', '\\'), '[', '\[') + '%' ESCAPE '\'` to escape embedded escape characters first.

Comment: Do note that the pattern `[[]` is not an empty search pattern. It is a search pattern that looks for a left bracket `[`